# icon file cannot be found for notifyicon WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

The resource can't be located, I'm sure this is super simple and I'm just missing something? The similar questions on stack didn't help me

```
        App.icon = new NotifyIcon();
        icon.Click += new EventHandler(icon_Click);
        icon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(typeof(App), "icon.ico");
        icon.Visible = true;
```

the icon.ico file is in my Resources.resx

I've tried setting it as a resource and doing a clean and rebuild, any more solutions?

Thanks :)

Comment: If it's in your resource file then it should be accessible with `Properties.Resources.icon`

Comment: If I add then I get an error 'IDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'Resources' and if I fix that with application.Properties.Resources.icon I get cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Icon' to 'System.Drawing.Size'

Comment: Replacing the third line with icon.Icon = appname.Properties.Resources.icon; Worked, Thanks for your help :)